# Background Tint Overlay Issue

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with having an overlay of a .5 opacity div on a background image when attempting to create a tinted overlay.

The issue is that the `div` with the `background-color` property isn't in front of the background image. Please see my codepen and code below:

http://codepen.io/mattsmith/pen/evzBJW

**CSS**

```
* {
  font-family: Open Sans;
}

.component {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 126px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(66, 66, 66, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.background-image {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/tk82k0V.png');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;

  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="component">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="background-image"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anybody explain why this could be? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a negative `z-index` on `.background-image` (e.g. `z-index: -1`). But personally I would structure it differently, that is, I would set the background image on `.container` and then `.background-image` becomes `.overlay` (then you wouldn't need a negative z-index).

Comment: I was just about to edit my post regarding this. I would do that myself but the platform I am adding this code to requires it to be this way. I will try the z-index again with a negative quantity, as when I tested with `1` and `999` I had no luck. Thanks for your input :)

Comment: That worked - I'll have to look into why a negative would work but 1 vs 999 didn't. Thank you!

Comment: @ewm No problem. Yeah, `z-index` can be a complex creature... I just think of it as follows: a positive value is bringing the element closer to you and a negative value is "pushing it" further away "into the screen".